# App crashing because of cache issue

Tags: ios, applications, crash

Our app is in development and currently in test flight. The latest version release crashes when the calendar feature is engaged. Our dev agency says it’s a cache issue and instructed us to delete the app, restart the device and redownload the app from test flight. While this works to solve the crashing issue, it’s not an ideal solution. Does anyone know of a solution to this issue that will solve for the cache issue without having to delete app/restart device/reinstall app in test flight?

Comment: I'd have thought that would be one for the devs to figure out. They know all about the app; we know nothing.

Comment: Agreed. However, we are having issues with our dev agency and because of this, we're moving away from them. In the meantime we've resorted to researching solutions ourselves to help move them along

Answer (score 1):

The caching issue is specific to your app, not a generic iOS problem. The solution would have to be internal to your app, and thus implemented by your developers.

Comment: @jksoegard - Thank you for taking the time to reply to our question